# Indicate beforehand required tag(s) when posting

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app, meta, asking-questions

On Meta Stack Exchange, questions need to be tagged with at least 1 from [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), or [support](/questions/tagged/support). It would be nice to the user to select one of these tags when asking a question, just like in the web interface:

[image: suggested tags on desktop]

instead of giving an error message after he tries to post the question:

[image: error message on Android app]

> At least one of these tags is required - 'bug feature-request discussion support'.

(all the more so since the user can only try to post the question once every 60 seconds…)