# Waiting 60 seconds every time I make a mistake when posting a question is a pain

Tags: feature-request, android-app, rate-limiting

Waiting 60 seconds every time I make a mistake when posting a question with the Android app is a pain. Couldn't this delay be lowered to some more user-friendly delay?

> [image]

(mistake = e.g. forgetting a compulsory tag)

Comment: This is API rate limiting meant to prevent flooding the server. (keep in mind that other apps, not official, can also use this same API)

Comment: @ShadowWizard how can you flood if the delay is more than one second?

Comment: Not sure about the technical details, but I am sure there is good reason for the rate limiting, and that it's coming from the API side.

Comment: What kind of mistake are you referring to?  Perhaps I'm not familiar enough with the Android app, but I think it would help to be more explicit in the question what specifically you're referring to.

Comment: @D.W. Added in question.

Comment: Do you mean that editing on the same throttle as making a post? Huh.

Comment: @JeremyBanks just talking about posting, not editing

Comment: For the specific issue with required tags, there is actually a [separate feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259731/indicate-beforehand-required-tags-when-posting) but this one here is more general. :)

Comment: Hopefully if this gets changed the implementors won't get inspired by the comment rate limiting thingy. A 30-second rolling limit would be far worse than a 60-second flat one

Comment: This is a _lot_ of status bar icons for an android phone. I'm curious...

Comment: @JanDvorak Got to do stuff when waiting for 60 seconds.